# Spring Boot Health Check for different Modules

Tags: controller, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

I have created a program with multiple modules, of which 4 of them have rest controllers. I want to create a health check using spring boot actuator in order to have a detailed check on all dependencies of a module, including the modules with a rest controller. Currently, I am easily able to show the database, but for each of the 4 modules, the other 3 are also dependencies, so I want to be able to see if those are running fine too.

How do I create a custom health check which checks the health status of those other 3 modules as well? I thought of using the jar file after build and calling the url after running the jar file but it does not seem to work?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. kindly try to explain the question clearly with clarity on the main part itself. Please post your research on the same with the script/code/images along with the difficulty you face. To get a clear idea of how to ask a question.See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create custom `HealthIndicator(s)`

Spring boot is a runtime framework, so you can create beans of custom health indicators right within the modules as long as they get "packed" together in the spring boot application artifact you're running (war/jar)

If the beans get scanned properly, the spring boot will recognize all of them and will "plug-in" into the health endpoint of the actuator.

In a nutshell,  Health Indicator is a hook, here is an example of the most simple one:

```
@Component
public class RandomHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
    // note its a regular spring bean, so you can inject your components here
    @Override
    public Health health() {
       Health.Builder status = Health.up();
       return status.build();
    }
}
```

For more comprehensive tutorial about this topic see, for example, [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-health-indicators), there are others of course.